# Accessing an instance variable outside class with attr_reader

Tags: ruby, rest, web-services, methods, instance-variables

I've got a method sitting in a Services class. This method is going to take the name of a service and a key:value pair of an attribute I want to build a string query for to call out to the service i'm passing in.

I'm sending this build string query to the service via RestClient and capturing the response in a variable: `@response`

I want to carry this variable out of the Services class and use it. I've got `attr_reader` included in my class but i keep getting `nil` for `@response` when I try to access the response outside of Services.

What am I missing?

Example of my code:

```
class Services 
  attr_reader :response
  def query_method(service,key,value)
    where = "#{key}=#{value}"
    @url = root_url + service + where
    @response = RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :get, :url => @url)
  end
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to access `@response` since it's an instance variable of the class `Service`. Rather what you want is `query_method` to return the query string. You could do something like `response = query_method(...)`

Comment: "but i keep getting nil for @response" - yes, it will be nil, until you call `query_method`.

Comment: So my problem is that I'm using this for testing so I need to hop up and down layers (Ruby/Cucumber) with the responses I'm generating in my Services class. I want to take a variable with my stored response and then validate it via RSpec at a different layer. If that makes sense.

Comment: make sure you are calling `query_method` first before accessing `@response`. 

Your test would look something like (I'm assuming its a controller)
`it 'sets @response' do
  service.query_method(...)
  expect(assigns(:response)).to eq(expected_value)
end`

Comment: @partydog could You please show how are You trying to access that variable? Or maybe the code You are using in Rspec?